# White noise when recording microphone, muted or unmuted

Tags: windows, audio, microphone

I've recently discovered, annoyingly, that any microphones connected to my computer produce background noise when connected, regardless of whether the microphone is muted or not. The noise seems to be sitting at -60 to -50db. Noise reduction in audacity works well but produces a watery effect.

I'm using Windows 10, and do not have Realtek Audio Manager

Answer (score 2):

You're probably just hearing the less-than-stellar noise-floor of the ip amp.

The regular i/o on a home computer is just about good enough for Skype, nothing more.
A USB pre-amp is what you really need.

Prices go from 'cheap' to *'omg wow'* - this is a googled selection at just the first store I hit, no recommendation or affiliation - http://www.gear4music.com/Soundcards/USB.html

Don't pay more for an interface than you paid for the microphone…. though if you cannot get one for less than the price of the mic, you perhaps need to be looking at another mic too ;-)

Alternatively, there are all-in-one solutions, like the [Blue Yeti](http://www.bluemic.com/yeti/) series - mic+USB in one unit.